# How to replace inequality condition with base level data

Tags: r

I need to check `dat` to make sure `max` is > `min`.  If this condition is not met, then I would like to replace it with the `base` data for the `date`.  I am currently using a `for` loop, but it is really slow when a lot of these conditions are met.  Is there a faster way to do this?

**Sample Data**

```
library(dplyr)

base <- data.frame(id = rep(1, 10), date = seq_along(1:10), max = c(90, 80, 70, 60, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10, 1), min = c(70, 60, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10, 0, -10, -20))
dat <- data.frame(id = rep(1, 10), date = seq_along(1:10), max = c(90, 80, 70, 60, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10, 1), min = c(70, 60, 100, 40, 30, 20, 100, 0, -10, -20))
```

**Code**

```
chk <- which(dat$min >= dat$max)

for (j in unique(chk)){
  chk2 <- filter(base, date == dat[j,2])
  dat[j,3] <- chk2[1,3]
  dat[j,4] <- chk2[1,4]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the logical index ('i1') to replace the 'date' in 'dat' with the corresponding 'date' in 'base':

```
i1 <- !with(dat, max > min)
dat$date[i1] <- base$date[i1]
```

Or use `ifelse` in a single step:

```
ifelse(dat$max > min, dat$date, base$date)
```

#### Update

If the OP wants to replace the 'max' and 'min' column values with corresponding elements in 'base'

```
 dat[i1, c('max', 'min')] <- base[i1, c('max', 'min')]
```

Comment: This doesn't replace `max` and `min` when the inequality conditions is met

Comment: @Amstell I negated it with `!`.  If I quote your description `If this condition is not met, then I would like to replace it with the base data for the date`.

Comment: Thanks!  What I am after is this `i1 <- !with(dat, max > min)`  `dat$max[i1] <- base$max[i1]` `dat$min[i1] <- base$min[i1]`

Comment: @Amstell Thanks for the clarification.  I updated the post.